# Error creating a proxy from wsdl

Tags: .net, web-services

I am using a .net 2.0 client to create a proxy from a wsdl file. This wsdl has some types included from other xsd files.

When I create proxy, the types that are specified in xsd documents are created even though they are referenced with in the wsdl. I tried it some other clients like Soap UI, java. They all work fine. Is there a tweak to work this out?

Comment: I think you mean the types that are specified in the xsd are *not* created even though they are referenced in the wsdl?

Comment: I will provide a sample wsdl and its associated xsd file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to Microsoft support, they said it is not possible in .net 2.0, either we have to use wcf or create a monilithic wsdl with all the types inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a stripped down example (just a couple lines of wsdl, and a few lines of xsd that reproduce the problem).

To answer the question we need to see the actual type definitions and how they're included in the wsdl.

I've often found that stripping the example down to just the bare essentials will expose the problem.